# Vagrant::Butcher "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" when trying to "cat /etc/chef/client.pem"

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, sudo

Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS with Vagrant 1.4.3 and Vagrant::Butcher 2.1.5.

I get the following error at the end of "vagrant up":

```
...
[2014-03-17T22:50:56+00:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 245.448117502 seconds
[2014-03-17T22:50:56+00:00] INFO: Running report handlers
[2014-03-17T22:50:56+00:00] INFO: Report handlers complete

[Butcher] Creating /home/testuser/vagrant_test/.vagrant/butcher
[Butcher] Failed to create /home/testuser/vagrant_test/.vagrant/butcher/DEV-35-51-client.pem: Vagrant::Errors::VagrantError - The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

cat /etc/chef/client.pem

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

The Chef client runs successfully, and our cookbooks are all installed.  One of them is the *sudo* community cookbook, and I'm thinking we blew away an entry that the *vagrant* user needs to execute *cat* to read the client.pem file.

Can anyone tell me what that might be?

**UPDATE:**

1) The vagrant user is part of the "sudo" group:

```
$ grep sudo /etc/group
sudo:x:27:vagrant
```

2) The sudoers file contains an entry to let the "sudo" group run any command:

```
# This file is managed by Chef.
# Do NOT modify this file directly.

Defaults      env_reset
Defaults      secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# User privilege specification
root      ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
nagios    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/nagios/libexec/


# Members of the group 'admin' may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo     ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: So... why not report this on the vagrant-butcher plugin? https://github.com/cassianoleal/vagrant-butcher

Comment: The `sudo` group has sudo access, but it's not passwordless. @tmatilai's answer seems to be spot-on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ultimately not a vagrant-butcher issue; that plugin only happened to suffer from the problem first. Also any following vagrant operation would have failed too.

Vagrant requires password-less sudo permissions. Seems that the base box declared it in `/etc/sudoers` which you overwrite with the sudo cookbook.

You have at least the following choices:

1. Set the `node['authorization']['sudo']['passwordless']` attribute to true.
2. Don't include the default recipe of the sudo cookbook at all.
3. Use the [sudo LWRP](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/sudo#lwrp) to grant password-less sudo access to the vagrant user.
4. Use or build a base box which already uses `/etc/sudoers.d/`.

Comment: Not entirely sure why, but I had to do #1 and #4

Answer (score 5):

*tmatilai* covered the issue very well, however I thought I'd post my solution here for future reference.  I found the same workaround as he mentioned as option #3, to write a recipe adding a sudoers.d config file for the vagrant user.  This forced me to modify the *sudo* community cookbook to support the SETENV option.  Otherwise you get the error:

```
sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to preserve the environment
```

The resulting file is /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant, note that it requires *both* NOPASSWD and SETENV:

```
# This file is managed by Chef.
# Do NOT modify this file directly.

vagrant  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:SETENV: /bin/
```

Here are the changes I made:

File: sudo/recipes/default.rb

```
# if the node belongs to the "development" environment, create a config file
# for the vagrant user, e.g. /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant
if node.chef_environment == 'development'
  sudo 'vagrant' do
    user      'vagrant'
    runas     'ALL'  # can run as any user
    host      'ALL'  # from any Host/IP
    nopasswd  true   # prepends the runas_spec with NOPASSWD
    setenv    true   # prepends the runas_spec with SETENV
    commands  ['/bin/']  # let the user run anything in /bin/ without a password
  end
end
```

File: sudo/resources/default.rb

```
# add new attribute "setenv"
attribute :setenv,     :equal_to => [true, false],  :default => false

# include it in the state_attrs list
state_attrs :commands,
            :group,
            :host,
            :nopasswd,
            :setenv,
            :runas,
            :template,
            :user,
            :variables
```

File: sudo/providers/default.rb

```
# in render_sudoer, add setenv to the variables list
variables     :sudoer => sudoer,
              :host => new_resource.host,
              :runas => new_resource.runas,
              :nopasswd => new_resource.nopasswd,
              :setenv => new_resource.setenv,
              :commands => new_resource.commands,
              :defaults => new_resource.defaults
```

File: sudo/templates/default/sudoer.erb

```
# generate SETENV option in the config file entry
<% @commands.each do |command| -%>
<%= @sudoer %>  <%= @host %>=(<%= @runas %>) <%= 'NOPASSWD:' if @nopasswd %><%= 'SETENV:' if @setenv %> <%= command %>
<% end -%>
```